# Get-AzureADUser filter - "A script block cannot be evaluated without input"

Tags: powershell

Can somebody explain to me why the following works:

```
$email = 'fred@bloggs.com'
Get-ADUser -Filter {mail -eq $email}
```

But when I do this:

```
$email = "fred@bloggs.com" 
Get-AzureADUser -Filter {mail -eq $email}
```

I get:

```
Get-AzureADUser : Cannot evaluate parameter 'Filter' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two commands use two different types of filters.

`Get-ADUser` uses PowerShell Expression Language syntax. It can accept surrounding `{}` even though they technically should not be used because it is not really a scriptblock. This also means that you can use a subset of PowerShell operators like `-eq`, `-like`, etc. The proper syntax for this filter is `"mail -eq '$email'"`. The inside quotes are needed because PowerShell will expand the string inside of the double quotes before passing it to `Get-ADUser`, which will result in `mail -eq user@domain.com` (notice there are no quotes surrounding the email address) and throw an error.

`Get-AzureADUser` uses an oData v3.0 filter statement. That specification does not allow for PowerShell operator syntax as it has its own rules. It also does now allow the scriptblock (`{}`) syntax. The proper way to construct this filter is `-Filter "mail eq '$email'"`. Notice it uses `eq` rather than `-eq`. With oData filters, you gain access to functions that can make data retrieval and manipulation easier. An example of using a function is `Get-AzureADUser -Filter "startswith(Mail,'$email')"`.

See [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) to see more information on the `-Filter` parameter for `Get-ADUser`.

See [Get-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0) to see more information on the `Get-AzureADUser -Filter` parameter.

An additional link [oData Filter Querying Collections](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/#queryingcollections) contains a table of acceptable operators and functions to add significant capabilities for querying.